# jQueryUI autocomplete always showing all options

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-autocomplete

I have array of objects. Clicking by input - data appears, chosen data adds, but autocomplete doesn't works (all data always shown). If i trying simple array, and simple `source: array`, autocomplete works.

```
$(function() {
    function log( message ) {
        $("<div>").text(message).appendTo("#log");
        $("#log").scrollTop(0);
    }

    $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            response($.map(resultUsers, function (value, key) {
                return {
                    label: value.name,
                    value: value.Id
                }
            }));
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#search").val(ui.item.label);
            log( ui.item ? ui.item.label + " Id " + ui.item.value : "Nothing selected");
        }
    });
});
```